# Magento: Cart showing empty on checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, php-5.4, nginx

When i click buy button items are adding into the cart.But When I do checkout, after logging from account and then filling shipping details,the cart becomes empty.Normally the URL which is followed for checkout is www.mysite.com/checkout/onepage/ but as my cart is getting empty the URL redirects to www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/.I am working on php5, magento 1.7 and nginx as local host.I am clueless about what is happening here.
I am newbie.

Comment: I would check cookie setting in admin panel

Comment: How cookies are related with this

Comment: related question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33384/why-does-shopping-cart-gets-empty-after-sometime

Answer (score 1):

This question is not answerable for us, because it is too localized.

Some things about cart and login:

When you login, magento loads your account's quote. Then these two quotes are merged. This happens here `\Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::loadCustomerQuote`

The other thing which might be interesting for you is, that the session id is renewed after login. This happens here `\Mage_Customer_Model_Session::setCustomerAsLoggedIn`.

Something happens, that either the quote is lost, the products or the session after login.